# Installing ubuntu - Boot fron UEFI?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (as a dual boot to Windows 10)and burned a DVD with the right image. However, when restarting the computer, it listed the options to boot from as:

```
UEFI: <DVD>
<SSD>
<HDD>
<DVD>
```

Does anyone know what the difference between the first and fourth is and which one I should use?
Thanks!

Comment: If UEFI secure boot is off, you normally get two boot options. One UEFI: flash drive and other just flash drive or BIOS. I assume it is the same with DVD. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. And if Windows is UEFI, you really want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. What brand/model system? What video card/chip?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Hi, I built it myself: the motherboard is UEFI (MSI B350 tomahawk) with RX480 graphic card and R5 1600x CPU. So the first one is the better choice then? ETA: maybe it is BIOS after checking the motherboard manual..??

Comment: It says it's an UEFI AMI BIOS

Comment: Many vendors still call it BIOS since they assume (perhaps correctly) that users to not know what UEFI is. With AMD graphics you have some issues. AMD is in process of redoing drivers and some drivers now are obsolete or only for old cards & some only work with some models of Cards/chips.Trying AMDGPU-PRO 17.10 On Ubuntu 17.04 (does not work directly)
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-PRO-Ubuntu-17.04 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver

Comment: The choice depends upon how you installed Windows.  Run msinfo32, click system summary, and look at the BIOS mode which should be either legacy or UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

UEFI is typically the preferred method if your cooperating operating system (in this case, Windows 10) is also installed in that method. One way you could tell is if you are able to configure Secure Boot in your BIOS.

For backward compatibility, most UEFI implementations also support booting from MBR-partitioned disks, through the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) that provides legacy BIOS compatibility. So you can think of that other option as a kind of fail-safe in case your system has issues with using the newer standard of UEFI. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface]

Comment: Mixing BIOS-mode and EFI-mode installations is usually possible, but very awkward, and in some cases it's impossible to mix boot modes; so "preferred" in this case is a very strong preference. For more on this topic, see [my Web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) on the CSM.